# Streaming past and future data using Akka Streams

Tags: reactive-programming, akka-stream

I am trying to understand better Akka Streams concept on the following example. Consider a bank account. It has a past transaction history and there will be new transactions coming. Now we want to use it as a source for an Akka stream. But its data will be used in 3 different scenarios:

1. A consumer app collects all past transactions and prints a report.
2. A consumer app is a transaction monitor that prints all new transaction starting with a time the app started.
3. A consumer app combines functions of (1) and (2): it first prints all past transactions and then prints all arriving transactions.

What do we have here in terms of Akka streams? Is the difference in stream sources that feed otherwise same flows and sinks with different data? Or is the source the same (it's all transactions from the same bank account) but we need to apply different filtering operations to obtain different results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akka stream Sources can be combined like any other `Iterable` that exists within scala.

Based on your example, say we have historic transactions that are persisted in a database.  We could use something like [slick streaming](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/dbio.html#streaming) to get those transactions from the db:

```
val historicSource : Source[Transaction, _] = ???
```

There would also be realtime transactions (possibly coming from a messaging system):

```
val realtimeSource : Source[Transaction, _] = ???
```

These two Sources can be combined:

```
val combinedSource = historicSource ++ realtimeSource
```

Those combined events can then be used by the same stream processing logic; for example you could `println` any transaction over $1,000.00:

```
val isLargeTransaction = (_ : Transaction).dollarAmount > 1000.0

val reportTransaction = (transaction : Transaction) =>
  println s"Large Transaction: $transaction"

combinedSource.filter(isLargeTransaction)
              .runWith(Sink foreach reportTransaction)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a great explanation.